# Updating multiple dicts on one assignment

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict to which I've added a value of list of 10 empty dicts.
I then try to add a *single* value to one of the dicts in a list. 
But it seems that I set it to all dicts in the list. 
Any ideas? How can I implement this it this cant work?

```
bids={}
bids[1]=[{}]*10
bids[1][0][1]=0
```

bids prints as

```
{1: [{1: 0}, {1: 0}, {1: 0}, {1: 0}, {1: 0}, {1: 0}, {1: 0}, {1: 0}, {1: 0}, {1: 0}]}
```

while I expect:

```
{1: [{}, {1: 0}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[{}]*10` will create a list with 10 references to the *same* dictionary object. By manipulating this one instance, the changes affect the whole list, obviously.

Use `[{} for _ in range(10)]` instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
[{}]*10
```

creates an empty dictionary, and then a list of 10 elements, all of which are that dictionary. In code, it's equivalent to:

```
d = {}
[d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d, d]
```

You want a list of 10 *different* dictionaries, all empty initially. In code, you'd write it as:

```
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[{} for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be that instead of values which are lists of 10 empty dicts, you might want or be able to make each value a dict of dicts, depending on what you plan to what else you plan to do with them:

```
from collections import defaultdict

bids={}
bids[1]=defaultdict(dict)
bids[1][0][1]=0

print bids
# {1: defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {0: {1: 0}})}
```

Each value will automatically be initialized to a separate empty dictionary the first time you reference one. Dictionaries don't preserve order like lists do, but that's something you many not require. Even if it is, you may be able to just sort them by their keys as necessary.